# blank error message on errThrown-ajax call

Tags: iphone, ajax, web-services, cordova, cross-platform

```
$.ajax({
            url: loginPath,
            password: Password,
            username: Username,
            type: "GET",
            error: function(xhr,textStatus,thrownError)
            {
                alert(textStatus+"   "+thrownError);
            },
            success: function(data)
            { 
                alert(data);
            }
       });
```

I am developing an application in Phonegap for iphone & android, my application needs to call web services at a point, now when i call the web service as above, the alert(textStatus+"   "+thrownError); show only "error" the thrownError parameter is blank, all this happens when i run the application on the device/simulator, if i run my code on safari it works just fine without any error, but on the device it somehow screws up. Can some1 tell me what i'm doing wrong? or is there any problem with the web services.

P.S: when i say device i mean iPhone 3GS, as of now i am testing it on this device.

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert(xhr.statusText);` in the error function.